# How to Create MySQL Trigger programmatically from C# if not already created?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I would like to create the trigger programmatically only if not created.

I am not able to create trigger programmatically from `C#`. If I am executing the same trigger from **MySQL Workbench 6.3** than its successfully  created the trigger.

I am receiving the error while executing from `C#` as below.

> Error at line
>
> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().
>      "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER //  CREATE  TRIGGER Trigger_Lifetouch  AFTER INSERT 
>   ON mat.lifetou' at line 1"

My Code as below

```
public void createTrigger()
    {
            string _query = " DELIMITER // " +
                            " CREATE "+
                            " TRIGGER `Trigger_Lifetouch`  AFTER INSERT  "+
                            " ON mat.lifetouch "+
                            " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN "+
                            " INSERT INTO mat.lifetouchrespirationrate (ByDevSessionId) VALUES(2);       "+
                            " END;" ;

            using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed || con.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }

                    int retn = 0;

                    using (var transaction = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                    {
                        retn = 0;
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                        cmd.CommandText = _query;

                        try
                        {
                            retn = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());

                            if (retn > 0)
                            {
                                logger.Debug(" Trigger Created ");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                logger.Debug("  Trigger Not Created  ");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.Debug(ex );
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Common practice is to leave DBA work to DBA environments, and keep it out of your app.  Is there a reason you need to create a trigger this way?

Comment: My Application should create Database, Tables, and trigger if not available. I am using Service Stack (Web Service) , C# based application.

Its the client requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger creation can not not be done through MySqlCommand.
you should use (new MySqlScript([ConnectionString], [TriggerScript])).Execute();

this will create the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy at runtime value from variable _query and paste it to MySql Query editor. It's an error when you construct the query. You forgot to add at the end "DELIMITER ;"

Answer (score 0):

try and used **@** in creating a queries

```
string _query = @" DELIMITER //
                   CREATE
                   TRIGGER `Trigger_Lifetouch`  AFTER INSERT
                   ON mat.lifetouch
                   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                   INSERT INTO mat.lifetouchrespirationrate (ByDevSessionId) VALUES(2);       
                   END
                   //;" ;
```